# How can I use URLs without ".xhtml" in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

How can I use a mapping like `localhost:8080/project/index` instead of `localhost:8080/project/index.xhtml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prettyFace](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) for it.